# Имя функции не определено

Tags: python, tkinter

Я использую библиотеку tkinter. В приложении определены текстовое поле и кнопка. При нажатии кнопки должна срабатывать функция, которая выводит текст из текстового поля. Но при нажатии выходит ошибка:

> NameError: name 'get_url_data' is not defined

```
from tkinter import *
def btn_click():
    slug_number = slug_input.get()
    get_url_data(slug_number=str(slug_number))

root = Tk()
root['bg'] = '#fafafa'
root.title('Name')
root.geometry('300x250')
canvas = Canvas(root, height=300, width=250)
canvas.pack()
frame = Frame(root, bg='red')
frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
btn = Button(frame, text='Кнопка', bg='yellow', command=btn_click)
btn.pack()
slug_input = Entry(frame, bg='white')
slug_input.pack()
root.mainloop()

def get_url_data(slug_number):
    print(slug_number)
```

Comment: код выполняется сверху вниз. Поэтому сначала нужно определить функцию, а потом уже использовать.

Comment: И возьмите за принцип хорошего стиля (для читабельности кода) определять все функции сначала, если только нет явной необходимости её позже определить.

Comment: Да, я это понимаю, просто впервые пытаюсь делать интерфейс, и поскольку не получилось сделать его с конструкцией if name == main я попытался сделать хоть так, чтобы проверить как оно вообще работает.

Comment: @lian.lun если понимаете, значит вопрос можно закрывать? Если все еще что-то не понятно, укажите что конкретно не понятно.